# Facebook graph API can_upload doesn't always work

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, upload

My application allows the user to upload photos to Facebook. Before the photo is uploaded I show the user a list of all their photo albums from Facebook. According to Facebook can_upload Determines whether the UID can upload to the album and returns true if the user owns the album, the album is not full, and the app can add photos to the album. 
From trying it out I can upload to some albums where can_upload is 0 my question is how do I tell if I can upload to any given album?

Comment: I've found that the can_upload boolean to be inaccurate as well. I just prevent them from uploading to their profile pictures. That seems to prevent most issues.